# how to copy and rename file with for loop in bash script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, loops

How I can copy all file *.html to *.php with For loop?

help me...

this my script :

```
#!/bin/bash
list="$(ls *.html)"
for i in "$list"
do
  newname=$(ls "$i" | sed -e 's/html/php/')
  cat beginfile > "$newname"
  cat "$i" | sed -e '1,26d' | tac | sed -e '1,21d' | tac >> "$newname"
  cat endfiel >> "$newname"
done
```

or you have another ide ?

Answer (score 6):

```
for f in *.html; do cp $f ${f%.html}.php; done
```

Answer (score 3):

Here you go:

```
for i in *.html; do mv "$i" "${i%.html}.php"; done
```

In RedHat Linux and derivatives there is a `rename` utility that simplifies this to:

```
rename .html .php *.html
```

In Debian Linux and derivatives there is a `rename` utility that simplifies this to:

```
rename 's/.html$/.php/' *.html
```

Check `man rename` or `rename --help` to see how to use the implementation you have. Sometimes the utility is called `rename.pl` instead of simply `rename`.

Answer (score 1):

Can omit the for loop altogeather if you have perl packages installed.

```
#!/bin/bash
rename 's/html/php/' *.html
```